# Kali OS Not found, not booting

Tags: kali-linux, boot-loader

I have Kali Linux installed on my laptop's SSD, I have another SSD on which I wanted to install Windows as a backup. The process was successful, but the next day I went to boot up my laptop (with Kali) and it said there was no OS installed, but I know that Kali is installed. I checked by using a Kali Live USB. Do I need to install grub somewhere different? This is NOT a dual-boot, BTW.

Comment: is Windows installed?

Comment: No. I am building a Linux-only laptop. New SSD and memory.

Comment: then, why did you talk about Windows in your question?

Comment: I said it is on another SSD, I switched them. I wanted people to know that I put a new SSD in the laptop. If you read the question, you would know that.

Comment: the description in your question is unclear ... it is unclear if one or two SSD are installed ... `I wanted to install Windows` is also vague

Comment: It sounds like you want to use Kali for your desktop, that's not what it's meant for, and not something it's suitable for.

Comment: I am now confused also, do you want to keep the windows SSD and install linux Kali again, or is this just a case of your laptop not booting the SSD? It seems like you just need to reinstall the bootloader if you just want linux.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the issue was.  @jsotola, the reason I mentioned the 2 SSDs is so you would know that the laptop originally had Windows installed, then I swapped out SSDs to install Linux "bare-bones".
Since the laptop previously had Windows installed, the Windows Boot Loader is still active and was first in the boot order (why I mentioned the other SSD). I created a Live USB and was able to change the order via the command line.